# Get two unique random values from php multidimensional

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

The lack of knowledge I would be a multidimensional PHP, make me confused to continue my project, anyone can help me with PHP multidimensional? So, I've some multidimensional PHP and then I want to get two value unique from a random array with certain conditions. for more details, below:

```
$array = Array(
 "LABEL1" => Array(
              'value 1',
              'value 2',
              'value 3'
             ),

 "LABEL2" => Array(
              'value 1'
             ),

 "LABEL3" => Array(
               'value 1',
               'value 2'
             ),

 "LABEL n" => Array(
               'value n'
             )
 )

 $output = random($array);
 print_r($output);

 //output a $output

 Array(
  [LABEL unique n] => Array(
               [0] => 'value 1'
              )
  [LABEL unique n] => Array(
               [1] => 'value 2'
               [n] => 'value n'
              )
  )

 //or

 Array(
  [LABEL1] => Array(
               [0] => 'value 1' // always index [0] from LABEL n
              )
  [LABEL3] => Array(
               [1] => 'value 2' //get index > [0] from LABEL n
              )
  )

  //or

  Array(
  [LABEL2] => Array(
               [0] => 'value 1' // always index [0] from LABEL n
              )
  [LABEL1] => Array(
               [1] => 'value 2' //get index > [0] from LABEL n
               [2] => 'value 3' //get index > [0] from LABEL n
              )
  )

  //or

  Array(
  [LABEL2] => Array(
               [0] => 'value 1' // always index [0] from LABEL n
              )
  [LABEL3] => Array(
               [1] => 'value 2' //get index > [0] from LABEL n
              )
  )
```

is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble in this code given your sample input is:

When the "second randomly targeted subarray" only has one element and that element's key is the same as the "first randomly targeted subarray", then the second subarray will be empty in the result array.  Execute the demo link to reveal this issue.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d0136b91d402367fec396ac7318ccde1dc68de2))

```
$array=[
    "LABEL1"=>['value 1','value 2','value 3'],
    "LABEL2"=>['value 1'],
    "LABEL3"=>['value 1','value 2'],
    "LABEL9"=>['value n']
];

$rand_keys=array_rand($array,2);  // generate an array of two random keys from $array
foreach($rand_keys as $i=>$key){
    if($i==0){
        $subarray=$array[$key];
        $column=array_rand($subarray);  // column to be excluded from 2nd iteration's subarray
        $result[$key][$column]=$subarray[$column];  // store the randomly selected value
    }else{
        $diff=array_diff_key($array[$key],[$column=>'']);  // store all elements that are not from the same column as first subarray
        $result[$key]=$diff; // when subarrays are LABEL2 & LABEL9 or LABEL9 & LABEL2, then the second subarray will be empty
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Possible Output:

```
array (
  'LABEL1' => 
  array (
    1 => 'value 2',
  ),
  'LABEL3' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value 1',
  ),
)
```

Possible Output:

```
array (
  'LABEL1' => 
  array (
    0 => 'value 1',
  ),
  'LABEL2' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Comment: @Luckyman How do you want to handle cases like the second Possible Output?  Please add more clarity to your question.

Comment: @Luckyman Alternatively, do you want to store a random element from a random subarray, then filter (remove) all subarrays that only have the same key as the first stored element?  By doing this, you ensure that you will never have an empty second stored subarray of elements.  Your sample outputs are a little ambiguous because the first stored subarray always contains the first element of the randomly selected subarray.  The more I read your question, the more confused I become.